# Is VS2015 intellisense broken with enums?

Tags: vb.net, enums, visual-studio-2015, intellisense

Just upgraded from VS2013 to VS2015 Enterprise Update 3 and discovered that intellisense seems broken with enums.

With VS2013, typing space after, for instance:

```
dim myEnum as MyEnumType =
```

... would immediately give a choice of enum values of the correct type.

This was **also true** with more complex situations, where, when choosing from a number of overloaded versions of a method, you could down-arrow through the overloads till you got to the right overload, then type space again, and it would give you a choice of the right enum values of the correct type, for the argument you had got to in the list.

Here's what VS2013 did, for instance:

[image]

However, this is the VS2015 equivalent, on the exact same line of code, after scrolling through to the correct overload:

[image]

As you can see, it gives a completely wrong list of possible options.

There was a similar problem with a previous version of Studio that eventually got fixed after the whole community howled in pain.

It seems to be back with VS2015 - a significant retrograde step. Now you have to know the exact type it's expecting before it will give you options.

A similar issue seems to have been [reported](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/1611220/problem-with-intellisense-with-visual-studio-2015-community-edition) a year ago re the Community Edition but it, or a more subtle version of it is clearly also affecting Update 3 of Enterprise.

Is there any way to reproduce the Common/All tabs behaviour of VS2013?

---

Edit: here are my selected options:

[image]

They're the same as I had in VS2013.

Comment: Can't reproduce the problem https://i.snag.gy/vEtW8c.jpg

Comment: Will edit shortly with more specific example.

Comment: @Sehnsucht - added a couple of screenshots comparing VS2013 and 2015

Comment: VS2015 has *many* problems, the Roslyn integration produced a large amount of bugs and changed behavior that affected just about everything.  Whenever you see something you don't like, be sure to tell **Microsoft** employees, the people that can actually do something about it.   We can't.  Click the [New Issue button](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues), if you do it quickly then there are only three thousand four ahead of you.

Comment: @HansPassant Thanks for this - I've raised an issue (https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/12981).  If you'd like to make this an answer I'd be happy to accept it.

Answer (score 1):

What the intellisense shows is the list of member according to the current signature (or what the compiler thinks it could be), not according to the overload tooltip.

For example see this [image: intellisense/overload demo]
It shows the same overall behaviour as in your post.

But to obtain it, after having written the comma after `"caption"` I changed the current overload tooltip manually using up/down arrow on keyboard.

*Note, it was not mandatory to change it manually even without that it was proposing me some overload which takes an `IWin32Window` for first argument even with an already present string as first argument*

Then I pressed space and the intellisense showed what is appropriate given the context not the tooltip.

In your post we can see it's not the same overload in both screen.
I can't say for sure it is what happened for you (given I changed the overload tooltip on purpose) but if I had to bet, I would go that way.